# Convert any number to positive. How?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to convert any number (negative or positive) into a positive number.. For example, my input can be 4545 or -4545, I need the out  come to be positive value **4545**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to simply multiply by $-1$. For example if you have a number $-a$ then multiply by $-1$ to get $-a \times -1 =a$. If the number is positive then multiply by $1$.

Or if you are aware of the [Absolute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value), then take the absolute value of the number.

Comment: This is the problem. I am getting the first value from an equation. I do not know it would be positive or negative. But I want it in positive. So I need to apply some equation on it if I am right.

Comment: cool. Absolute Value is working.

Answer (score 14):

With a calculator, you could make a number positive in one of two (simple) ways:

- $\text{abs}(x)$
- $\sqrt{(x^2)}$

The first one is recommended, but the second one will work as well as the square root function on most calculators returns the positive root. Squaring a real number always makes it positive, so taking the square root of a number squared returns the positive number.

Comment: Yes, by all means use $\operatorname{abs}(x)$! You don't want to waste time squaring and taking roots (you'll also have to cope with imprecisions)...

Comment: Precisely. The second option is a work-around only (like if your calculator doesn't have an absolute-value function).

Comment: In textbooks, the first one is often written $\lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: no, square root give two results: +/-

Comment: @Sergei: to be pedantic, the square root symbol always means the principal square root, which is positive.

Comment: Thanks @El'endiaStarman for clarification. You helped me to see the difference between the symbol and ^(1/2)